# Create a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, artificial-intelligence, data-generation

I have python lists that I would like to convert into nested dictionary (later to be saved into json format). Below is the example of the lists and final json format (just an example of my use case data). Please direct me how to convert the list into dictionary.

Lists:

```
Auto = ["Ford", "Hundai", "BMW"]
Purchased = ["2018", "2019", "2021"]
Milage = ["30", "25", "15"]
Drive = ["Primary", "Secondary", "Primary"]
Places": {"offroad": "sometime", "expressway": "everyday"}
```

Final json format needed:

```
 {
      {"Auto": "Ford", 
       "Purchased": "2018",
       "Milage": "30",
       "Drive": "Primary",
       "Places": {"offroad": "sometime", "expressway": "everyday"}
      }

      {"Auto": "Hundai", 
      "Purchased": "2019",
      "Milage": "25",
      "Drive": "Secondary",
      "Places": {"offroad": "sometime", "expressway": "everyday"}
      }

      {"Auto": "BMW", 
       "Purchased": "2021",
       "Milage": "15",
       "Drive": "Primary",
       "Places": {"offroad": "sometime", "expressway": "everyday"}
      }
     }
```

Comment: Your result is not valid. Dictionaries can't be elements of sets. It should be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: And it's not valid JSON, either, since JSON doesn't have sets. Just arrays and objects.